# Why isn't the promise being passed on to the next then?

Tags: javascript, promise, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I am trying to determin whether the role of an ***admin*** in my app is a super user or not through this code:

> AdminServices.js

```
var isSuper_User = function(email) {
  models.admin.findOne({ where: { email } }).then(function(admin) {
    logger.debug("Fetching user with email: ", email);
    logger.debug("admin.role: ", admin.role);
    isSuper_User = admin.role === 'super_user' ? true : false;
    logger.debug("isSuper_User: ", isSuper_User);
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(isSuper_User)
    })
  }).catch(err=> 
    logger.debug(err.toString())
    );
};
```

> admin_routes.js

```
router.get("/isSuperUser/:email", function(req, res) {
  logger.debug("req.params.email: ", req.params.email);


 adminService.isSuper_User(req.params.email).then(isSuper_User => {
    logger.info("isSuper_User returned from promise: ", isSuper_User);
  });

});
```

logger is a module that allows to customize the logging in the terminal.
However when I send the request with an email, for a user whose role is an admin the logger code inside admin_routes doesn't log anything. Everything inside AdminServices works perfectly though.
This is what I get in the terminal :
[image]
So the problem is with the way I handled the promise. But, I do not see what I've done wrong exactly.

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: @rayhatfield shouldn't I return a promise to the next then?

Comment: If the return from `then`/`catch` is not a Promise instance, `then`/`catch` wraps the return in a Promise instance automatically.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then See the Return Value section.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that you're clobbering `isSuper_User`.  You define it as a function, then later turn that very same variable into a boolean...  If you try to call `isSuper_User` twice, the second call isn't going to work.

Comment: One more notice: `isSuper_User = admin.role === 'super_user';` is equivalent of `isSuper_User = admin.role === 'super_user' ? true : false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `isSuper_User` is not returning anything.

Function should return the `promise`

```
var isSuper_User = function(email) {
  return models.admin.findOne({ where: { email } }).then(function(admin) {
    logger.debug("Fetching user with email: ", email);
    logger.debug("admin.role: ", admin.role);
    isSuper_User = admin.role === 'super_user';
    //admin.role === 'super_user' already returns true or false so no need of ternary.
    logger.debug("isSuper_User: ", isSuper_User);
    return isSuper_User;
    //No need of promise wrapper here.
  }).catch(err=> 
    logger.debug(err.toString())
    );
};
```

Comment: `catch` should probably return `Promise.reject(err)`, otherwise it's going to return a Promise instance that resolves with `undefined` on error, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: This did the job. Thank yoou:)

Comment: @avejidah at some point in your code you need to log and swallow the error.I am not sure how its handled by OP however `throw error;` will do the job. no need of `Promise.reject`

Comment: @AhmedGhrib Updated the `ternary` statement also.

Comment: True.  Just thought it worth mentioning since the OP shows actual usage.  In the OP's calling code, `isSuper_Admin` can be `true`, `false`, or `undefined`.

Comment: I agree that @avejidah, It should end up with `500` response.

Answer (score 2):

You have to return the promise from the function. In the given code you are not returning anything, which is equal to `undefined`.

```
var isSuper_User = function(email) {
  return models.admin
    .findOne({ where: { email } })
    .then(function(admin) {
      logger.debug("Fetching user with email: ", email);
      logger.debug("admin.role: ", admin.role);
      isSuper_User = admin.role === "super_user" ? true : false;
      logger.debug("isSuper_User: ", isSuper_User);
      return isSuper_User;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      logger.debug(err.toString());
      throw err;
    });
};
```

Comment: Just return `isSuper_User`.  This is an anti pattern and shows a clear misunderstanding of Promises.

Comment: Can you explain it ? How it is anti pattern, It will really help me if you explain to me.

Comment: Read the Return Value section, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then  If `then`/`catch` returns a value that is not a Promise instance, that value will be automatically wrapped in a Promise instance.

Comment: Your previous `Promise.reject(err)` was, IMO, better.  The way you have it now, `catch` will return a Promise that is _resolved_ with "rejected."  E.g. the error will be squelched/swallowed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, @avejidah

Comment: `return Promise.reject(err);` is the same antipattern as `Promise.resolve`, you should simply throw the error. `.then/catch` already wraps the returned/thrown value/error into a promise.

Answer (score 0):

The `isSuper_User` function has no `return` statement.

It doesn't return a promise, it returns `undefined`.

You need to explicitly return the promise.

```
return models.admin.findOne....
```

Comment: It does return a Promise instance, and that Promise instance resolves with `undefined`.